# Using update from df2 to change values in df1 but getting error message, python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df which I am trying to use to updates the values.  There are thousands of rows but I am trying to give an example here.

df1

```
col_a     col_b
Steve     Doctor
Jack      Staff
Jack      Staff
Steph     Nurse
```

df2

```
col_a      col_b
Brittany   Dancer
Jack       Doctor
Steph      Nurse Practitioner
```

df -desired

```
col_a     col_b
Steve     Doctor
Jack      Doctor
Jack      Doctor
Steph     Nurse
```

Df2 has values that are not in DF1.  So how can I update df2 col_b with values in df2?

Comment: Did you mean how to update df1 with values from df2? Your wording is a little confusing.

Comment: i am trying to use df2 as a mapping file.  change the values in col_b